# SpreadsheetEntry.getKey() returns a key preceded by 'spreadsheet%3A'

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I use Google Spreadsheet API to copy a document from one account to another and then I want to return the key for the newly created spreadsheet.

The copying is done by retrieving the template spreadsheet, creating a new one with `SpreadsheetEntry newDoc = new SpreadsheetEntry();` then setting the `id` of the new one to the template spreadsheet `newDoc.setId(template.getId());`. Then I insert the new spreadsheet

`newDoc = service.insert(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full"), newDoc);`

I want to return to the caller two things: link to the newly created spreadsheet and its key.
I get the first through `newDoc.getSpreadsheetLink().getHref();` and it returns `https://docs.google.com/a/bridgeworks.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Asl_Vu_YG4J-dDc5NHpwTFVRZFNiVENnRUxOb21XLVE`

Then I call `newDoc.getKey();` and it returns `spreadsheet%3A0Asl_Vu_YG4J-dDc5NHpwTFVRZFNiVENnRUxOb21XLVE`

The key seems to be preceded by `spreadsheet%3A`. But why? Can I safely remove it and return just the key?

If I use

`URL worksheetUrl = urlFactory.getWorksheetFeedUrl("0Asl_Vu_YG4J-dDc5NHpwTFVRZFNiVENnRUxOb21XLVE", "private", "full");`

it succeeds but

`URL worksheetUrl = urlFactory.getWorksheetFeedUrl("spreadsheet%3A0Asl_Vu_YG4J-dDc5NHpwTFVRZFNiVENnRUxOb21XLVE", "private", "full");`

fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Documents List API defines two types of IDs: resource ID and untyped resource ID. The former is of the format [type]:[id], while the latter is just [id]:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#terminology_used_in_this_guide

You can safely remove the [type] part from a typed resource ID to get the untyped one.